# Action/Signal to time mapping software

Tags: mapping

I am looking for a software or a script (any language) that would help me to map an execution of a batch of actions based on relative timing.

In simpler terms - Imagine I have 100 unique IDs/cells, I put them in 10x10 grid (or linearly) and at specific times (eg t+10ms, t+140ms) I record which of the IDs are sent to the serial port (or callbacks are called and I can write the serial port transportation code).

It's a similar idea to the mapping of LED pixels throughout the time.

With GUI, would be cool if there was a grid and I just toggle specific cells on/off at specific time intervals and when I play back - they fire callbacks or whatever.

With a script, I could record individual cells separately with a button press and then play them back all together.

Is there anything similar that currently exist?

Comment: Firing an action is instant, so the "pixel" will blink very briefly, right? So the UI will be mostly empty, with a flash from time to time, right? Or do you want some kind of "spreading" to make actions more visible? I don't know any application like this. If I knew a good frame-by-frame pixel-by-pixel video editor, I would suggest a program could parse the video (or series of bitmap files) and fire actions based on that, but that's a far shot. Parsing individual bitmaps is easier, and they can be made into a movie like that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iRvEAZUwUA

Comment: You need to control lile LCD array like this https://goo.gl/images/3pxvXC  ? Try customize something from LCD control. Like http://bitmap2lcd.com/blog/tag/c-array-to-image/

Comment: Or http://320volt.com/en/atmega32-ile-bilgisayar-kontrollu-126x15-ledmatrix-animasyon-yazi/

Comment: That's a great starting point - but that would be quite tedious to create bitmaps for every frame.